# Unable to read variables from docker file during docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have a docker file in a simple React app that shows a photo. I must pass the URL to this photo when I run a new container from the docker image. I'm trying to use an ENV variable that will be set on the docker run. The variable is being set, I can see it when I go to the inspect section of the docker desktop app, but my docker file is not using it.

This is my docker file:

```
ARG source

FROM node:alpine AS development

ENV source=$source

EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /react-app

COPY ./package.json /react-app
RUN npm install

COPY . .

ADD ${source} /react-app/src/data

CMD npm start
```

I have tried to use the ARG and change its location after and before the FROM.

I have tried moving the ADD (where I'm using the variable) and putting it just after the ENV.

I have tried to use `$source` instead of `${source}`.

I have tried removing the ARG and just using the ENV because I know the ARG is only used in the `docker build` and not `docker run` but I had no luck.

This is my docker run command:

```
docker run --rm -ti -e source=https://**myblobstorage**/BlobData/pic.jpg -p 3000:3000 -i myimage:latest
```

What am I doing wrong here? I need to pass the parameters from my docker run and not while building the image.

Comment: If you're using the environment variable in your React app, then the issue might be that the React app runs in the browser on a user's machine, where the environment variables in the container aren't available.

Comment: it's not about the react app if I hard code the link inside the dockerfile everything works fine and the file is copied to the container but if I try to pass it as a parameter it doesn't get copied

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Maybe you need to add the ARG before and after FROM?

Comment: Thank you @Mogens for your suggestion I just tried it and it didn't work either.